# Angular JS ui-mask with type="password"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

I am developing an app with input field, and for pattern using angular js ui-mask.

**HTML**

```
<input type="tel" class="input-field " data-ng-model="registrationField.debitcard" ui-mask="9999    9999    9999    9999" placeholder="Enter ATM/Debit Card Number"  ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask-placeholder-char="space" id="debitCardFld" ui-options="{clearOnBlur: false}"/>
```

1. With `type="text"` the code works fine.
2. But when we use `type="password"`, on `focus` of the field, the **spaces** in `pattern` is also masked.

Only when the user types, it has to mask the characters.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Ref: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a fake password input with type text using a custom font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'password';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://sites.google.com/site/rafaelcastrocouto/download/password.ttf);
}

input.key {
  font-family: 'password';
  width: 100px; height: 16px;  
}
```

Notice that this only raises more security concerns.
good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```js
const email = "yeison@gmail.com";
const num  = "3194726641"

function enmascararEmail(email) {
    const email_parts = email.split('@'); 
  const percent = 40;
  const prefix_percent = (email_parts[0].length * percent) / 100;
  const prefix_email = email.substring(0, prefix_percent)
        .concat('*'.repeat( email_parts[0].length - (prefix_percent-1)));

  return prefix_email.concat('@').concat(email_parts[1]);
}

function enmascararNumberId(numero) {
  const firts = numero.substring(0, 2);
  const last = numero.substring(numero.length - 1, numero.length);
  const mid = '*'.repeat(numero.substring( 2, numero.length - 2).length);
  return firts.concat(mid).concat(last);
}

function enmascararNumberPhone(numero) {
  const last = numero.substring(numero.length - 2, numero.length);
  const mid = '*'.repeat(numero.substring( 0, numero.length - 2).length);
  return mid.concat(last);
}

console.log("number id", enmascararNumberId(num));
console.log("number phone", enmascararNumberPhone(num));
console.log("return email", enmascararEmail(email));
```